# Write the following numbers as a sum of two squares..

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Write the following numbers as a sum of two squares:

$$(a) 13\times17$$
$$13\times17=221$$
$$m=13=(3^2+2^2) \space \text{and} \space n=17=(4^2+1^2)$$
$$[(3)(4)+(2)(1)]^2+[(3)(1)-(4)(2)]^2=14^2+(-5)^2=221$$

I had no problem solving this one.  However, the next problem is giving me trouble because $19^{10}$ is such a large number.

$$(b) 13\times19^{10}$$

$$13\times19^{10}=79703861351413$$  I can only find this number using wolfram.  My calculator wont display all the digits.  Which is a problem.

$$m=13=(3^2+2^2) \space \text{and} \space n=19^{10}=(c^2+d^2)$$

Is there a easy / simple method I can use to find $c$ and $d$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hint: 13=9+4, $19^{10} $  is a square.

Comment: I already know all this.  I need to know how I am supposed to break up $19^{10}$ into a sum of two squares.  For example: $n=19^{10}=(c^2+d^2)$.

Comment: @maroon.elephants:  you don't need to break $19^{10}$ into the sum of two squares.  Given that you can break $13$, just multiply $4$ and $9$ by (what?)

Comment: @maroon.elephants Take a second to read Mark's answer carefully. He's given you the answer. Remember that the product of two squares is again a square.

Comment: Ohh, that makes so much sense now.  $19^{10}*(3^2+2^2)=19^{10}*13$.

Answer (score 0):

Since the excellent answer by Mark Bennet has been accepted I'll undelete my stupid one:

write $19$ as a sum of two squares then

- write $10$ in binary `1010` so $19^{10} = (19^2)(((19^2)^2)^2$
- use the identity $(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2) = (ac-bd)^2 + (ad+bc)^2$ repeatedly